# RSpec Capybara locator not finding link text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a page with a simple `<a>` tag with the text `Upload Video`. I set a break point in my rspec test and do this:

```
Capybara.current_session.find('.primary')
#<Capybara::Node::Element tag="a" path="/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/label/a">

Capybara.current_session.find('.primary').text
"Upload Video"

Capybara.current_session.find('.primary').visible?
true
```

So we know for sure there is a link with `Upload Video` text on the page.

But when I do

```
Capybara.current_session.has_link?('Upload Video')
false
```

I get `false`. From the [docs](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/63a12e7ba064fe326b36d014ede8c9269855a6af/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb#L262) it seems the `locator` can be element text. So why isn't this working?

This alternative seems to work:

```
Capybara.current_session.has_selector?(:css, 'a.primary', text: 'Upload Video')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML defines an `a` element to be a link when it has an 'href' attribute, without one it is considered a placeholder for a link - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element.  For that reason Capybara defaults to requiring an `href` attribute exist when finding links. I'm going to guess your "link" doesn't actually have an `href` attribute.  You can make Capybara find that by passing `href: nil` as an option

```
 Capybara.current_session.has_link?('Upload Video', href: nil)
```

Comment: That's correct. My link has no href attribute. Thanks :)